# Decoding AES Strings containing spaces

Tags: php, aes, mcrypt, encryption

In receiving a URL from an iPhone app, we are decrypting a string created in Objective-C and passed to our PHP website as a GET variable.

We are decoding using:

```
mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $padded_key, base64_decode($base64encoded_ciphertext), 'ecb');
```

Which is working fine the majority of the time  But sometimes, we receive a string containing a space, for example:

```
mypage.php?score=IEZrdQ5iUECe9 xyfTY5Cg==
```

Then the decryption fails and we are left with a result like this:

[the result http://mattbee.co.uk/temp/mess.png](http://mattbee.co.uk/temp/mess.png)

Has anyone any idea how to handle strings with spaces in the middle of them, should spaces even exist?  I would have thought encoding might have something to do with it but converting to UTF-8/UTF-16 didn't help.

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Base64 data contains whitespace every 64 characters, and 0-2 equal signs at the end. So the iPhone app should percent-encode it before sending as a GET variable.

Answer (score 2):

Base64 can represent arbitrary bytes, which is just what is necessary for ciphertext. Do not recode to anything else.

Some software inserts spaces and line-breaks in base64-encoded strings, so they fit into emails and other line-length limited formats. These should be ignored or removed when decoding.

If there are spaces inside the base64-encoded string, you could strip them out before decoding, though I think that [base64_decode](http://php.net/base64_decode) should do this automatically.

Another note: Do not use ECB-mode, it is insecure. Use CBC-mode (with a random initialization vector sent with the message). Or even better, don't encrypt parts of a URL, use SSL (or TLS) instead, which will handle all the details for you.

Answer (score 0):

You could go with bin2hex then use pack('H*', hex) to decode the string. The only issue I know with this method is that the string can grow very big.